# csv file to 2d array cpp w/ newline characters

Tags: c++, csv

```
void generateSudokuFromCSV(std::ifstream &infile, sudokuT sudoku) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(infile, line);
        if (!infile.good()) break;
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            std::string ch;
            std::getline(iss, ch, ',');
            if (!iss.good()) break;
            std::istringstream converter(ch);
            converter >> sudoku.board[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for reading in a csv file and setting up the sudoku board. It works only if there are commas after the last number in each line. This is what the file looks like:

```
0,8,6,0,5,0,3,0,0
4,0,7,0,9,0,0,0,0
5,2,0,8,7,0,0,0,0
0,5,0,0,8,0,0,0,0
7,1,0,0,4,0,0,6,5
0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,1,8,0,4,3
0,0,0,0,6,0,1,0,9
0,0,5,0,3,0,8,7,0
```

The code works if the file looks like this:

```
0,8,6,0,5,0,3,0,0,
4,0,7,0,9,0,0,0,0,
5,2,0,8,7,0,0,0,0,
0,5,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,
7,1,0,0,4,0,0,6,5,
0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,
0,0,0,0,1,8,0,4,3,
0,0,0,0,6,0,1,0,9,
0,0,5,0,3,0,8,7,0,
```

but that is not typical for csv, and not how excel converts it. So how can i change the code to handle this properly. Can getline take multiple delimiters?
Thanks for your time and insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::getline(iss, ch, ',');
```

will fail to read the last field. To account for that replace the line

```
if (!iss.good()) break;
```

with the following:

```
if (!iss.good())
{
   iss.clear();
   std::getline(iss, ch);
   if ( !iss.good() ) // This is a real problem.
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but im having another issue now. When I open the file in text editor or excel it looks just like it does in my question. 9 lines long, but when I read it with getline is 1 line long. do you know why this is?

Comment: I fixed my one line problem, but I did what you said and it is exiting when j = 8

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to eliminate the `iss` stream and process the `line` string directly. Instead of a strict ',' delimiter, you could consider any non-number a delimiter.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    size_t si = line.find_first_not_of("0123456789");
    std::string ch = line.substr(0, si); // substring before delimiter
    if (ch.length() == 0) break; // empty string
    std::istringstream converter(ch);
    converter >> sudoku.board[i][j];
    if ((si + 1u) >= line.length() || si == std::string::npos) break; // no more data after delimiter
    line = line.substr(si + 1u, std::string::npos); // substring after delimiter
}
```

If you want to be stricter with the format, replace the lookup part with

```
size_t si = line.find_first_of(',');
```